# Mongoose updating array to default value when updated

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to update a date feature every time a user clicks my app using mongoose's fineoneandupdate with upsert. When a new user is initially created everything gets setup correctly. However, when the system goes to update a user that already exists it updates the date feature that I am telling it to, but also forces an array of strings back to being an empty array.

Here's my schema:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
            _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            spuser_EID: String,
            taken_onboarding_survey: Boolean,
            our_last_seen: Date,
            surveys_taken: [String]
          });
```

Here's the new user that I'm telling it to use as an update:

```
var updateUser = new User({
            "our_last_seen": new Date().getTime()
          });
```

Here's the console log of that user object before it goes in:

```
{ surveys_taken: [], our_last_seen: 2018-08-09T17:35:58.756Z }
```

And Here's the findoneandupdate call:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({
              spuser_EID: params["userEID"]
            },
            updateUser,
            {
              upsert: true,
              new: true
            },
            function(err, userdoc) { // callback
              if (err) {
                // handle error...
              } else {
                // handle document...
```

Basically, I want it to not update that array while still updating the "our_last_seen" feature. I'm not exactly sure what's causing the error, especially since I haven't set a default value in the schema. I'm totally stumped, so if there's any additional information that I've missed please let me know. Any help you can give would be extremely appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: don't create instance with `new User()`... Use the object directly in `$set` parameter

Comment: That worked. Cheers!